# Perceptron with weights of bounded condition number

Tags: matrix, optimization, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Let *N* be a (linear) single-layer perceptron with weight matrix *w* of dimension *nxn*.

I want to train *N* under the Boolean **constraint** that the *condition number* *k(w)* of the weights *w* remain below a given threshold *k_0* at each step of the optimisation.

Is there a standard way to implement this constraint (in pytorch, say)?

Comment: No built-in functionality like that in PyTorch, I believe. But it's easy to implement it.

Comment: You could add a regularizer to apply such constraint.

Comment: Thanks both, @bobcat and @Ivan! Would accept as an answer if anyone of you spelled out the details of a possible such implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each optimizer step, go through the list of parameters and recondition all matrices:

(code looked at for a few seconds, but not tested)

```
def recondition_(x, max_cond): # would need to be fixed for non-square x
    u, s, vh = torch.linalg.svd(x)
    curr_cond = s[0] / s[-1]
    if curr_cond > max_cond:
        ratio = curr_cond / max_cond
        mult = torch.linspace(0, math.log(ratio), len(s)).exp()
        s = mult * s
        x[:] = torch.mm(u, torch.mm(torch.diag(s), vh))
```

Training loop:

```
...
optimizer.step()

with torch.no_grad():
    for p in model.parameters():
        if p.dim() == 2:
            recondition_(p, max_cond)
...
```